# Setting up static ip in server and router for mysql communication in windows server

Tags: windows, mysql, ip, router, routing

I'm a begginner in this topic of routers,
I have a client that bought an static ip looks like this 201.122.204.101 however that ip was set up on router that is a hg532e (I don't know if that affects) and the server is able to ping router but it is connected to another subnet that the router has that is the 192.168.1.254 server ip is 192.168.1.130 now I changed mysql bind-address to 201.122.204.101 that is the router ip address however the service won't start, is there any configuration that I still need to do?. Or I'm missing information? the server is windows 2012 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up port forwarding / NAT on the router so that incoming connections to `201.122.204.101` port 3306 are forwarded to `192.168.1.130` port 3306.

However, you must be careful with security issues here, since it is not safe to have a MySQL port reachable from the public Internet.

Comment: mmm so that's tall? oh okay then really sorry the dumb question, I did a test on the server but did not work but did a test on all the machines and it did work! haha oh well.. have a wonderful day man!